# Theme override support for custom components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

After the migration to mui v5 for react-admin, we realized that supporting theme overrides for our custom components seems to require more code than we expected. As it looks that this could be handled by the `styled` API, I would like to know if this is really required.

Here's an example of our Navigation link:

```
const PREFIX = 'RaMenuItemLink';

export const MenuItemLinkClasses = {
    root: `${PREFIX}-root`,
    active: `${PREFIX}-active`,
    icon: `${PREFIX}-icon`,
};

const StyledMenuItem = styled(MenuItem, {
    name: PREFIX,
    // Why do I have to do this?
    overridesResolver: (props, styles) => [
        { [`&.${MenuItemLinkClasses.active}`]: styles.active },
        { [`& .${MenuItemLinkClasses.icon}`]: styles.icon },
        styles.root,
    ],
})(({ theme }) => ({
    [`&.${MenuItemLinkClasses.root}`]: {
        color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    },

    [`&.${MenuItemLinkClasses.active}`]: {
        color: theme.palette.text.primary,
    },

    [`& .${MenuItemLinkClasses.icon}`]: { minWidth: theme.spacing(5) },
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I think that I would start to simplify the code to:

```
const PREFIX = 'RaMenuItemLink';

export const MenuItemLinkClasses = {
    root: `${PREFIX}-root`,
    active: `Mui-active`,
    icon: `${PREFIX}-icon`,
};

const StyledMenuItem = styled(MenuItem, {
    name: PREFIX,
    overridesResolver: (props, styles) => [
        styles.root,
        { [`&.${MenuItemLinkClasses.active}`]: styles.active },
        { [`& .${MenuItemLinkClasses.icon}`]: styles.icon },
    ],
})(({ theme }) => ({
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,

    [`&.${MenuItemLinkClasses.active}`]: {
        color: theme.palette.text.primary,
    },

    [`& .${MenuItemLinkClasses.icon}`]: { minWidth: theme.spacing(5) },
}));
```

The `overridesResolver` property is meant to resolve this object:

```
const theme = {
  components: {
     [PREFIX]: {
        styleOverrides: /* this object, it's the 'styles' arg of overridesResolver */,
     },
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just curious but why do we have to provide this resolver? Can't it be applied automatically by `styled`? It feels a bit boilerplaty

Comment: It can't be applied automatically by `styled` as the argument it receives is too heterogeneous. Now, you might only want to support the root key. In which case, yes, we could consider improving the default behavior for overridesResolver to use the `slot` by default to resolve it.